# Query 1:n relationships in RavenDb

Tags: c#, ravendb

i'm having problems indexing my data in RavenDB in a way I can query it as deserved:

I have a **list of Documents of type Product**:

```
public class Product
    {
        public string Id => Asin;
        public string Url { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Asin => Url.Split("/").LastOrDefault();
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public List<Category> Categories { get; set; } = new List<Category>();
    }
```

and a **list of type Snapshot**:

```
public class Snapshot
{
    public string Asin { get; set; }
    public DateTime Timestamp { get; set; }
    public string Price { get; set; }
    public int? Ratings { get; set; }
}
```

I should be able to create a **1:n relation** between **Product and Snapshot**, meaning:

One **Product** with a **unique field Asin** can have **many Snapshots with that Asin** that can be identified by a **unique field Timestamp** like:

```
public class ProductWithSnapshots
{
    public Product P { get; set; }
    public List<Snapshot> S { get; set; }
}
```

=> which I could query the way I need...

I am absolutely new to RavenDb and would be delighted if there was anyone out there who could help. I digged into the documentation (Indexing / Map-Reduce, Querying, etc.) and many posts, but I simply cannot find a better way to address my problem.

Many thanks, guys!

Max

Comment: What kind of query are you looking to make ?
I.e. get all snapshots per specific product ?

The Product document ID that is kept in the 'Asin' property within Snapshot is called 'a **Related Document**'.

<br>
See some Demos regarding related documents in the following links:
https://demo.ravendb.net/demos/csharp/related-documents/load-related-documents
and https://demo.ravendb.net/demos/csharp/related-documents/query-related-documents

Comment: Have you looked into the following **Document Modeling** chapter in RavenDB book ?
https://ravendb.net/learn/inside-ravendb-book/reader/4.0/3-document-modeling
i.e. **Common modeling scenarios** in https://ravendb.net/learn/inside-ravendb-book/reader/4.0/3-document-modeling#common-modeling-scenarios

Comment: many thanks, for you hints, @Danielle! I knew most of it but I guess I found the problem I want to solve at https://ravendb.net/articles/merging-documents-in-ravendb-with-map-reduce - this seems to do exactly what I need, but this sample is simply not working for my. In the last step, even if I narrow it down to a tiny 3-lines-of-code map, RavenDb is throwing tons of errors... do you know if there are any similar samples referring to the latest RavenDb version? I can't find any... Cheers, Max

Comment: What last step ? Are you creating an index ? Can you share your index definition ?